# Retrieving data from a has_many relationship in DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Given a simple case of two tables - Term and Definition - where Term `has_many` Definitions and Definition `belongs_to` Term, all terms and the corresponding definitions are to be fetched and displayed somehow.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
my $terms= $schema->resultset('Term')->search(undef, {  
  prefetch => 'definitions',  
});  

while (my $term = $terms->next) {
  my @terms;
  push @terms, $term->term;

  my $definitions = $term->definitions;
  my @definitions;
  while (my $definition = $definitions->next) {
    push @definitions, $definitions;
  }
  ...
}
```

It does the job but I was wondering if a different, less crufty approach could be taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $terms= $schema->resultset('Term')->search(undef, {  
  prefetch => 'definitions',  
});  

my @terms = $terms->all;

my @definitions = map $_->definitions->all, @terms;
```

This looks like what you are trying to do; I can't really tell.  The fact that you make a new array, push onto it, and then let it go out of scope doesn't really make any sense at all.  Anyway, if I understand you correctly all you wanted was the all method from DBIx::Class::ResultSet.

Comment: The array is nothing but a part of this example.
The `all` method is what I wanted indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[DBIx::Class::Manual::Joining](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBIx::Class::Manual::Joining) should help. See, for example, [Whole related objects](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBIx::Class::Manual::Joining#Whole_related_objects).

Comment: The examples don't really show how to extract related data; in particular, when relationships are of type `multi`.